# How can I plot 2 graph lines generated on the same plot , separately on two different plots in the image?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a diurnal graph, showing the variation in the concentration of a gas.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import dates as d
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
dataframe = pd.DataFrame( 
    columns = ['From Date',   'NO',          'NO2',       'NOx',    'CO',           'Ozone'],           
    data = [
        ['2018-12-30 00:00:00', 5.856666,    39.208341,   28.97,   331.280881,  19.778900],
        ['2018-12-30 01:00:00', 4.050059,    16.262145,   13.53,   454.031703,  25.075286],
        ['2018-12-30 02:00:00', 4.057806,    15.293990,   12.96,   466.502681,  24.825294],
        ['2018-12-30 03:00:00', 3.835476,    13.526193,   11.71,   446.526784,  25.033312],
        ['2018-12-30 04:00:00', 4.230690,    11.251531,   10.70,   355.638469,  25.748796],
        ['2020-01-01 05:00:00',    1,            2,        6.91,    4,             5],
['2020-01-01 06:00:00',            5,           10,        7.37,    13.2,          9],
['2020-01-01 07:00:00',            4,           13,        8.28,    4,             4],
['2020-01-01 08:00:00',            3,           9,         8.57,    3,             5],
['2020-01-01 09:00:00',            2,           4,         9.12,    4,             6]
    ]
)
dataframe['From Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe['From Date'])
dataframe = dataframe.set_index('From Date')
dataframe['Month'] = dataframe.index.map(lambda x: x.strftime("%m"))
dataframe['Time'] = dataframe.index.map(lambda x: x.strftime("%H:%M"))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
for month in dataframe['Month'].unique():
    df = dataframe.loc[dataframe['Month'] == month]
    df = df.groupby('Time').describe()
    ax.plot(df.index,df['NOx']['mean'], linewidth=6.0, label = month)
    
ax.legend()

ticks = ax.get_xticks()
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(ticks[0], d.date2num(d.num2date(ticks[-1]) + dt.timedelta(hours=3)), 5))
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(ticks[0], d.date2num(d.num2date(ticks[-1]) + dt.timedelta(hours=3)), 25), minor=True)
plt.show()
```

The result gives the following graph-
[Diurinal graph obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHubI.png)

Is there a way I can obtain the plot lines of '12' and '01' on two different plots instead of having them together as obtained by making any changes to the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to make `n` subplots based on the number of `Month` Values. Then `zip` the axes and the months together:

```
# Get the Unique Months
months = dataframe['Month'].unique()
# Create subplots based on the number of months
fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(months))

# Iterate over axes and months together
for month, ax in zip(months, axes):
    df = dataframe.loc[dataframe['Month'] == month]
    df = df.groupby('Time').describe()
    ax.plot(df.index, df['NOx']['mean'], linewidth=6.0, label=month)
    ax.legend()
    ticks = ax.get_xticks()
    ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(ticks[0], d.date2num(
        d.num2date(ticks[-1]) + dt.timedelta(hours=3)), 5))
    ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(ticks[0], d.date2num(
        d.num2date(ticks[-1]) + dt.timedelta(hours=3)), 25), minor=True)

plt.show()
```

[image: plot 1]

---

Or with `shareX` and `shareY` so axes are shared:

```
# Get the Unique Months
months = dataframe['Month'].unique()
# Create subplots based on the number of months
fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(months), sharex=True, sharey=True)

# Iterate over axes and months together
for month, ax in zip(months, axes):
    df = dataframe.loc[dataframe['Month'] == month]
    df = df.groupby('Time').describe()
    ax.plot(df.index, df['NOx']['mean'], linewidth=6.0, label=month)
    ax.legend()

ticks = axes[0].get_xticks()
axes[0].set_xticks(np.linspace(ticks[0], d.date2num(
    d.num2date(ticks[-1]) + dt.timedelta(hours=3)), 5))
axes[0].set_xticks(np.linspace(ticks[0], d.date2num(
    d.num2date(ticks[-1]) + dt.timedelta(hours=3)), 25), minor=True)

plt.show()
```

[image: plot 2]

---

This can be accomplished much more simply via [`groupby mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) + [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html):

```
dataframe['From Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe['From Date'])
df = dataframe.groupby([
    dataframe['From Date'].dt.month,
    dataframe['From Date'].dt.strftime('%H:%M')
])['NOx'].mean().unstack(level=0)

axes = df.plot(subplots=True, sharex=True, sharey=True,
               linewidth=6.0, xlabel='')
plt.show()
```

`df`:

```
From Date    1      12
From Date             
00:00       NaN  28.97
01:00       NaN  13.53
02:00       NaN  12.96
03:00       NaN  11.71
04:00       NaN  10.70
05:00      6.91    NaN
06:00      7.37    NaN
07:00      8.28    NaN
08:00      8.57    NaN
09:00      9.12    NaN
```

[image: plot 3]

Comment: Hey! This method seems great, but I plan on plotting for all the 12 months of the year, hence the 12 subplots obtained are quite small. Is there a way to fix that so the plots become readable?

Comment: Change the figsize `fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(months), figsize=(15, 8))` play around with the values, the first is the width, the second is the height.

Answer (score 0):

[subplot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html) should do what you want.

This is an example you could use to create 2 differents subplots. In your case you will only have to change the 4 last lines of code.

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)
fig.suptitle('Vertically stacked subplots')
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax2.plot(x, -y)
```